# Clojure - caching with atoms?

Tags: clojure

I have a number of threads that need to access a collection of values, some of these values also need to be persisted to a database when any changes are made to them so that I don't lose the state in case of a server reboot etc.

Currently I'm using an `atom` to store these values, I have a set of functions which I call when something in the `atom` needs to change.

Inside these functions I'm also persisting data to a database before calling `swap!`, I chose this approach because I need to frequently read the values inside the atom, and it doesn't seem performant to `open/close db connections` every time I'm interested in one of the values.

**the question:**

Is this approach viable? I'm interested to know if anyone has had success implementing a similar solution or are there pitfalls I should be aware of?

Comment: I'd put the storing of the data into a watch over the atom (`add-watch`)

Comment: Also consider using a `clojure.core.cache`-cache inside an atom. A little tricky the first time, but works like a charm.

Answer (score 3):

Atoms are fine.

An alternative approach would be to use https://github.com/clojure/core.memoize or core.cached directly, like suggested by Stefan Kamphausen.

Approach:

- Cache query results on the function level. This way you are sure that what you get back is exactly how the database would return it and not the way you would think it would serialize/deserialize.
- Invalidate key/args after you have inserted/changed something in the database.

One benefit of this approach is that you can tweak the caching behavior: TTL, LRU, FIFO, etc.

Demo:

```
(require '[clojure.core.memoize :as memo])

;; suppose this is a real DB
(def db (atom {}))

(defn my-get [k]
  ;; expensive database call
  (Thread/sleep 5000)
  (get @db k))

(def my-get-cached
  (memo/memo my-get))

(defn my-put
  [k val]
  (swap! db assoc k val)
  (memo/memo-clear! my-get-cached [k]))

(comment
  (my-put :foo "the value")
  (my-get-cached :foo) ;; wait 5 seconds, "the value"
  (my-get-cached :foo) ;; "the value", instantly
  (my-put :bar "other-value")
  (my-get-cached :foo) ;; "the value", still instantly
  (my-get-cached :bar) ;; wait 5 seconds, "other value"
  (my-put :foo "changed")
  (my-get-cached :foo) ;; wait 5 seconds, "changed"
  )
```