# clojure: Wrong number of args (0) passed to clojure.lang.PersistentArrayMap

Tags: clojure

Following along with [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52447729/8291921), I'm using `clojure.core.memoize` to memoize results of some db calls:

```clj
(def get-user-profile-cached
  (memo/memo (get-user-profile)))
```

`get-user-profile` returns a map.

I try to use the cached get in a let within a function:

```clj
(defn get-user-from-token [token]
  (let [user (get-user-profile-cached)
        id (:id user)]
    ...))
```

This let statement causes the following error: `clojure.lang.ArityException: Wrong number of args (0) passed to: clojure.lang.PersistentArrayMap`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: i'm ppretty sure you got extra pair of parens in `get-user-profile-cached`. it probably should look like this: ```(def get-user-profile-cached
  (memo/memo get-user-profile))```

Answer (score 2):

By using `(get-user-profile)`, you're already calling the function and making `memo` cache its result, the map.

Try passing `get-user-profile` instead, without the parentheses.